# JSP MYSQL error with quotes select query

Tags: mysql, jsp

I' trying to create a Select without success.

With MYSQL, in the where clause, the value goes with simple quotes -> 'value'. But, I don't know how to do it in the correctly way to don't get an error.

```java
 cn = ConnectionDB.getConection(); 

 Statement stmt = (Statement) cn.createStatement();

**String consulta = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title like \"'"+value+"'\" OR author like \"'"+value+"'\" OR editorial like \"'"+value+"'\"";**


//Then i execute the query

**rst = stmt.executeQuery(consulta);**
```

Comment: You really should be using prepared statements but if you want to just inject values into SQL like that, be aware that SQL uses single quotes not double. So replace `\"` with `'`.

Comment: I finally decided to use prepared statements, and the problem finished!. Thank you.